# wordpress is_main_query() breaks

Tags: php, wp-query

After upgrading to 3.9

the function `is_main_query()` breaks down and doesn't works the way we want

The following code

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
echo 'is_main_query: ' . ($query->is_main_query() ? 'y' : 'n');
 }
```

prints 'y' at the top of the page

and then keeps on printing 'n' for reasons best known to them..

The actual code which doesnt works

```
function hwl_home_pagesize( $query ) {

if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    return;
}


 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hwl_home_pagesize', 1 );
```

it also breaks the navigation menu of my site

Comment: What debugging information do you get?

Comment: How it breaks? And explain "the way we want". From your code I can see it is working as expected. WordPress has one main query and several other *sub queries* when a page loads. so, Printing `ynnnnn` is quite normal behavior.

Comment: So what should we use for home page query 
Currently i use :-   'is_home() && $query->is_main_query()'  which doesn't works

Comment: Please add the code you mentioned in your comment as it seems that it is the code "breaking" your site. Please edit your question. Adding debug information would also be a huge +

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Your code doesn't break my site, Works perfectly.